# List all combinations of a items into b groups of size c

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm looking for a way in Python to split an arbitrary number of items into an arbitrary number of even groups, and to obtain the list/array of all these splits.

So for example, given 12 items, there are 5775 ways of grouping them into 3 groups of 4. Calculating this is not an issue, but I can't seem to find a way to return a list or array of these 5775. I can get the first groups using:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(range(12), 4))
```

But how can I obtain the remaining groups from this?

The desired output for `a = 4`, `b = 2`, `c = 2` would be:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 3]]]
```

And for `a = 3`, `b = 3`, `c = 1`:

```
[[[1], [2], [3]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive generator that, at each level or recursion, computes all combinations of the (remaining) items. The next level of recursion receives only those items that have been not been used in the current level already (the *remainder*).

In order to prevent duplicates in terms of the group ordering we need to truncate the output of [`it.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) such that it doesn't yield a combination that has appeared in the remainder of a previous iteration before. Let `n` be the number of items and `g` the size of each group. Then the first item from `it.combinations` is `(0, 1, ..., g-1)` (in terms of the indices). The item `(1, 2, ..., g)` will be part of the remainder when the current item from `it.combinations` is `(0, g, g+1, ..., 2*g-1)` (this assumes `n % g == 0`). Hence, we need to truncate the output of `it.combinations` such that the first element is fixed (`0` in the above example). Because `it.combinations` produces the items in lexicographical order, this covers the first `(n-1)! / (n-g)! / (g-1)!` items (`!` denotes the factorial).

The following is an example implementation:

```py
import itertools as it
from math import factorial
from typing import Iterator, Sequence, Tuple, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


def group_items(items: Sequence[T], group_size: int) -> Iterator[Tuple[Tuple[T, ...], ...]]:
    if len(items) % group_size != 0:
        raise ValueError(
            f'Number of items is not a multiple of the group size '
            f'({len(items)} and {group_size})'
        )
    elif len(items) == group_size:
        yield (tuple(items),)
    elif items:
        count, _r = divmod(
            factorial(len(items) - 1),
            factorial(len(items) - group_size) * factorial(group_size - 1)
        )
        assert _r == 0
        for group in it.islice(it.combinations(items, group_size), count):
            remainder = [x for x in items if x not in group]  # maintain order
            yield from (
                (group, *others)
                for others in group_items(remainder, group_size)
            )


result = list(group_items(range(12), 4))
print(len(result))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result[:3])
pprint(result[-3:])
```

Note that the above example uses `remainder = [x for x in items if x not in group]` to compute what items should go to the next level of recursion. This might be inefficient if your group size is large. Instead you could also use a `set` (if your items are hashable). Also, if equality comparison (`==`) between your items is expensive, it would be better to work with indices rather then with the items and compute the `group` and `remainder` from these indices. I didn't include these aspects in the above code snippet in order to keep it simple, but if you are interested in the details, I can expand my answer.

Comment: Very similar idea, but yours seems to be quite a bit faster than mine...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a smarter or more concise way, but you can create a recursive function to pick `combinations` for the first list, then pick combinations from the items not yet used. Also, if order of both the items in the sublists and the sublists themselves does not seem to matter, that means that the first sublist will *always* starts with the smallest element (otherwise it would not be the first sublist), the second starts with the smallest of the remaining items, etc. This should cut down on the number of combinations and prevent any duplicate results from appearing.

```
from itertools import combinations

def split(items, b, c):
    assert len(items) == b * c
    def _inner(remaining, groups):
        if len(groups) == b:
            yield groups
        else:
            first, *rest = (x for x in remaining if not groups or x not in groups[-1])
            for comb in combinations(rest, c-1):
                yield from _inner(rest, groups + [{first, *comb}])
    return _inner(items, [])

for x in split(list(range(6)), 2, 3):
    print(x)
```

Sample Output (using lists of sets, but you may convert the sublists to list before yielding):

```
[{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}]
[{0, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 5}]
[{0, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 5}]
[{0, 1, 5}, {2, 3, 4}]
[{0, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}]
[{0, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}]
[{0, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}]
[{0, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5}]
[{0, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4}]
[{0, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

For (a,b,c) = (12, 3, 4) it yields 5775 elements, as expected. For longer lists, this will still take a lot of time, though.

Comment: Indeed, a very similar idea. Regarding your implementation, the loop `any(x in g for g in groups)` seems unnecessary since if an item is contained in the first group, it can't make it to the second. Or vice versa, the fact that an item made it to the second level of recursion means it can't be contained in the first group. Following that logic, it seems you would only need to check the last group, i.e. `not (groups and x in groups[-1])`. Also, why do you need to sort the items? Can't you just unpack the generator directly?

Comment: @a_guest You are right in both points! Still takes ~50% longer than yours, though.

Comment: Perhaps usage of sets slows it down, as it needs to compute the hash for each element (though that should be fast and cached for integers; but in any case it's an additional lookup). What if you use tuples instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set_partitions()` function in `more-itertools` package:

```py
# pip install more-itertools
from more_itertools import set_partitions
a, b, c = 12, 3, 4

results = []
for part in set_partitions(range(a), b):
    if all([len(p) == c for p in part]):
        results.append(part)

print(len(results))  # 5775
```

Parts of 5775 results:

```py
...
[[2, 4, 5, 9], [0, 1, 7, 10], [3, 6, 8, 11]]
[[1, 4, 5, 9], [0, 2, 7, 10], [3, 6, 8, 11]]
[[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 2, 7, 10], [3, 6, 8, 11]]
[[2, 3, 5, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [0, 6, 8, 11]]
[[2, 3, 5, 9], [0, 4, 7, 10], [1, 6, 8, 11]]
...
```

In case you wanna know what does it do, basically `set_partitions(range(4), 2)` yields the set partitions of [0, 1, 2, 3] into 2 parts:

```py
[[0], [1, 2, 3]], 
[[0, 1], [2, 3]], 
[[1], [0, 2, 3]], 
[[0, 1, 2], [3]], 
[[1, 2], [0, 3]], 
[[0, 2], [1, 3]], 
[[2], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Isn't this sort of wasteful? Seems like you generate orders of magnitude more combinations than you need in the end.

Comment: @tobias_k hahaha you are right. I am just proposing a quick understandable easy solution. If you don't mind spending time to save machine time, feel free to do so. But, man, we are talking about Python here, it's not like I really care about overhead in general in the first place ; )